# How to use local variable of main function globally

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently,

```
List<String> ls = List.filled(10, "0");

Future<void> main() async {
  final Directory localStorageDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

//then assign the file.readAsLines() to ls;
}
```

Can I,

not declare(and initialize) the variables before the main function,

but use the local variables of main function, globally(in rest all program)...

Thanking you...

Comment: Why you don't use it as a `static` varriable?

Comment: you can use dependency injection (e.g: get_it) for your purpose

Comment: either use `static`, like @Saddan says, or use singleton.

Comment: There isn't any real difference between a `static` variable and a global variable.  If you need a global variable, use a global variable.  Nothing stops you from assigning your local variable to the global `ls` variable.